# What does this javascript variable mean?

Tags: javascript

When I create variables I don't use brackets after equal sign.

Why does this code use brackets after equal sign? Can anyone explain this? I want to know what does it mean after equal sign.

```
var start = (new Date).valueOf(),
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This method returns the equivalence of the Date object in milliseconds.

The milliseconds are expressed as an integer representing the number of milliseconds between midnight January 1, 1970 (GMT) to the date and time specified in the Date object.

Comment: do you mean valueOf() function automatically convert Date object to millisecond?

Answer (score 2):

The paranthesis around `new Date` cause that to be evaluated first, so the date is created, and THEN call `valueOf` on the newly created date.

It's basically like doing

```
var d = new Date();
var start = d.valueOf();
```

but on one line.

However, it should be `(new Date()).valueOf()`.  What is there right now will error out.

Answer (score 2):

the intention of this is to shorten the following code:

```
var date = new Date();
var start = date.valueOf();
```

but you can't write:

```
var start = new Date().valueOf();
```

because theres no `Date().valueOf()` that can be used as constructor, so you'll have to add braces. the part in braces will be executed first (creating a new date), and `valueOf()` will be called on the result of the code in braces (read: on the constructed date). That said, the solution is what we got in your question:

```
var start = (new Date).valueOf();
```

the result of all this is a timestamp in milliseconds.

Answer (score 1):

Easy thing. `new Date` returns a date. Without brackets, it would be `new Date.valueOf()`. Since `Date` doesn't have a method `valueOf()`, this results in an error.

BUT, an instance of Date has this function. So we use brackets. `(new Date).valueOf()` is the same as

```
var start = new Date;
start.valueOf();
```

Answer (score 1):

The wrapping parens around `new Date` evaluates the call to create a Date object then calls a method of the date object -> `valueOf`.  An easier to understand example would be

```
(3 + 2) + 2; // = 7 - evaluates 5 then adds 2
```

the `valueOf` method is defined as:

> Returns the primitive value of a Date object. Overrides the Object.prototype.valueOf method.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date

You can actually achieve the same thing by

```
var start = +(new Date()) 
// returns the integer value of the date (in milliseconds) 
// aka the primitive value
```